# Synonym for "daily" of Latin origin?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

When talking about a year long interval I can say "annual" to mean "yearly". For example, "the annual yield is", "the interest rate is 25% per annum", or "the annualized interest rate is 25%" if the original rate given is daily/overnight rate.

Is there a similar Latin-based word for other periods, especially for a single day? I can say "per diem" where I would say "per annum", but what about other use cases?

"If you invest $10000 in our payday lending company, you can expect ??? gains of $15" or "Short on cash? Borrow from us! Our ???ized interest rate is only 1%!"

I know there are "diurnal" and "nocturnal", but they usually mean "day" and "night" as in "when the sun is up" and "when the sun is down".

Comment: Why would you purposefully look for a Latin origin word? That's backwards.

Comment: @William I won't exactly call it backwards, but it is exactly opposite to the aim of [the Anglish project](http://anglish.wikia.com/wiki/Main_leaf)

Comment: @William: Quidquid latine dictum sit, altum videtur.

Answer (score 21):

"Quotidian" (if it really has to be a Latin-based word).

Comment: Has it ever been used to describe interest rates? Or are interest rates only ever "daily" or "overnight"?

Comment: I would not say "never", but it is certainly not common.

Comment: Fun fact: in Italian, newspapers are called "quotidiani", i.e. literally "dailies". (The other word for them, "giornali", related to the English journal/journalism is also related to that meaning).

Comment: @UncleZeiv The same applies for French, and I presume other Romance languages too.

Answer (score 14):

***[Per-diem](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/per-diem)*** is a Latin expression still used in the English language:

> - by the day; for each day.

(dictionary.reference.com)

Example sentences:

> - *The popular governor collected the per diem allowance from April 22*
> - *A spokeswoman said that a separate state board sets per diem payments*.
> - *The six-member commission angered many lawmakers when it voted last year to cut pay and per diem by 18%.*
> - *Tax-free per diem allowance to defray living expenses away from home*.
> - *A budget that puts two players per hotel room, and offers a $30 per diem and salaries that top out at $26000*.

(wordhippo.com)

Comment: From the question: "I can say "per diem" where I would say "per annum", but what about other use cases?"

Comment: Here are a few usage examples: http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/diem

Comment: I would suggest that "per diem" belongs to specialised banking/financial/fiscal usage.

Answer (score 8):

The problem with @fbd's **quotidian** is it's often used to mean [*usual or customary; everyday*.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/quotidian)

Alternatively, also from Latin (but actually only coined in 1959) there's...

> [**circadian**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/circadian) *- noting or pertaining to rhythmic biological cycles recurring at approximately 24-hour intervals.*

Which adjective to use would depend significantly on the exact context. **Quotidian** would probably suit your daily office report, but your daily bowel movement fits better with **circadian**.

Comment: And *quotidian* even is used to mean *commonplace*, often with a slightly negative tone.

Comment: @bib: Yes, that's how I normally understand *everyday* (i.e. - *ordinary*). So your *everyday* clothes are by implication inferior to your *Sunday best* (which is idiomatically so common we don't usually even bother specifying *clothing*).

Answer (score 5):

Preface: I only saw that you already knew about 'diurnal' after writing the following. Please tell me if you prefer this answer's deletion.

What about the adjective [**diurnal**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/diurnal) (which no other post has suggested, as of the time of this post)? For more on its Latinate etymology, see [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=diurnal&searchmode=none).

More generally, have you read Wikipedia's  [List of Germanic and Latinate equivalents in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Germanic_and_Latinate_equivalents_in_English), which was where I first encountered 'diurnal' above as the Latinate synonym for 'daily'?

Comment: _Diurnal_ is the opposite of _nocturnal_, so it is more related to sunlight cycle.

Comment: "Diurnal tide" refers to the tides of 24-hour period, regardless of what time of the day it's high tide or low tide.

Answer (score 0):

If "Circadian" means approximately daily then logically "dian" should mean daily.  While this word is not used according to Google, it is perhaps an idea to create it.

Comment: We already have that word, and it’s a noun not an adjective. A *dian* per the OED is ”a trumpet call or drumroll at early morn”. It derives from Romance *dia* from Latin *dies* and is of course related to *quotidian*.